# What's the difference between Rust-oleum and Rust-oleum Professional?

Tags: painting, paint, spraying

I have been doing some painting lately and I am buying all of my supplies from Home Depot.  I have noticed two dominant paints there: RustOleum Professional which comes in an aluminum can that has some info painted on it, and then the normal RustOleum which comes in aluminum cans that have a label over them.

The Professional series cost more - is there a reason, or just marketing?

Answer (score 3):

I dont know what the technical differences are but Ive used both for painting parts on my Jeep and have noticed that the Professional version gives a much smoother finish and self levels a lot better.  If you have the patience get the Professional version in the can and brush it on.  Looks a million times better than the spray can.

Prep work for both versions has been about the same, wire wheel, clean with mineral spirits, prime, sand, clean, final coats.

Comment: The text on the website implies the Professional does not need a top code, where the regular is just a primer.